# How is the precise value of pi calculated?

Tags: geometry

We often see the value of pi(irrational) with large no of digits behind the decimal place. How is such precise value of pi calculated?

Comment: You  have [rapidly converging series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/series-that-converge-to-pi-quickly), which can be used.

Comment: $\pi=\frac41-\frac43+\frac45-\frac47+\frac49\dots$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has been asked several times. [Here is one such example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588141/how-is-the-value-of-pi-pi-actually-calculated/596555) where you may find some of the answers helpful.

Comment: @barak manos; How is this series developed?

Comment: @Lamichhane88: Taylor series of $\arctan$?

Comment: @barakmanos: That series is definitely *not* how large numbers of digits of $\pi$ are calculated.  It converges much too slowly.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That series is definitely how large numbers of digits of $\pi$ **can** be calculated. The question doesn't mention anything about efficiency.

Comment: @barakmanos: I interpreted the word "is" in the title to ask about practical methods, i.e. those that actually have been used to calculate large numbers of digits.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I interpreted it as if OP could not figure out how the decimal digits of $\pi$ possibly be calculated. I would tend to guess that OP would just as well refer to any other irrational number for that matter, and just so happen had $\pi$ in mind. But that's more of an interpolation on OP ratings, plus the fact that the answer to this question could easily be found here and elsewhere... So I suppose that only OP could provide the actual meaning behind this question...

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to calculate $\pi$ you can divide the circumference of a circle by its diameter, but such a method involves taking precise and accurate measurements and there is always some error to be accounted for. [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) has listed methods and formulas to calculate $\pi$, but if you want 5 user friendly ways, [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Pi) they are.

**Note:**
The precision to which pi can be calculated and the time taken to do so approximately depends upon the computers and algorithms used and how they have been optimised.

Comment: If its only about easy (which it isn't): A Monte-Carlo method (extremely slow conv.) is to choose points with random $x,y$ coordinates between -1 and 1. And then counting those for which $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le 1$ and relating the count to the total number of points (that gives you $\pi/4$).

Comment: in the limit for $\infty$ points